# How to get data in has_many :through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many-through

I'm following [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and [this tutorial](http://www.gitmatt.com/posts/5) to learn more about has_many :through association in Rails. I created an app called school. And I have this inside my schema.rb file:

```
create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "teacher_id"
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "quantity"
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "teachers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

My teacher model:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :courses
    has_many :students, :through => :courses
end
```

My student model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :courses
    has_many :teachers, :through => :courses
end
```

My course model:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :teacher
    belongs_to :student
end
```

And my `/courses` view now looks something like this (I'm using scaffold):

[image]

When I go to `/teachers/1`, I want to display all `students` name and `quantity` associated with that teacher.

The current view of `/teachers/1` is like this:

[image]

I try to make it by using this code but it's not working:

```
<% @course.each do |c| %>
    <p><%= c.quantity %></p>
<% end %>
```

So, how to display all `students` name and `quantity` associated with that teacher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @teacher.courses.each do |c| %>
    <p><%= c.student.name %></p>
    <p><%= c.quantity %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks to msergeant and Jan!

Comment: `<%= c.student.name %>` is correct one. You just forgot the `.name`. Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: how about the JSON? I try to update my show.json.jbuilder file to `json.extract! @teacher, :id, :name, :created_at, :updated_at
json.extract! @teacher.courses, :student.name, :quantity` but it give me `undefined method `name' for :student:Symbol` error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the name of relation on variable with teacher object.

```
<% @teacher.courses.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.quantity %>
<% end %>

<% @teacher.students.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks to msergeant and Jan!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this code:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @teacher.name %>
</p>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
</tr>
<% @teacher.courses.each do |c| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= c.student.name %></td>
        <td><%= c.quantity %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_teacher_path(@teacher) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', teachers_path %>
```

Thanks to msergeant and Jan!